# Getting a percentage of a variable

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner in Javascript en Google Tag Manager, so I have a problem. I need to make a new variable that takes a certain percentage of an eCommerce variable (revenue). I tried different things but I keep getting errors. Thus far I got this:

```js
var percentage = (function() {
    return function(n,percent){
     return n*percent/100;
    };
    
})();
    
console.log(percentage(98, {{Ecommerce - Revenue}}));
```

I hope someone can help me with this!

Answer (score 1):

You just need a simple function and invocation:

```js
//declare the function
function percentage(n,percent){
     return n*percent/100;
    };
    
//invoke it
console.log(percentage(98, 10));
```

Unless you're specifically trying to create some kind of [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)/[IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) then do:

```js
//function closure
var funcHolder = function(){

   function percentage(n,percent){
     return n*percent/100;
    };
    
    //return enclosed function for usage outside of the function
    return { percentage: percentage};
   }();
    
//invoke the returned function using the closure
console.log(funcHolder.percentage(98, 10));
```

The above is an example of the [revealing module pattern](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-javascript-design/9781449334840/ch09s03.html)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. It's still not working, maybe my code is just not right. I need to get 98% of my revenue variable in Google Tag Manager. That's the reason why I had {{ecommerce - revenue) in the code. Is there another solution for this that you know?

Comment: I'm not really sure what that's got to do with your question? If you have a different question, then you should ask it as another question.

Answer (score 0):

If you define your own scope using the self calling function construction then you have to place your code within this self calling function.

```js
(function() {
  var percentage = function(n, percent) {
    return n * percent / 100;
  }
  console.log(percentage(98, 200));
}());
```